# как добавить в файл (vim) ^D простым нажатием <ctr+d>?

Tags: vim

Недавно была такая необходимость: смог это сделать, но после закрытия vim и его повторного открытия, при нажатии  ничего не записывается...

Comment: так запишите команду в ~/.vimrc

Comment: команда будет только для ^D, а если захочу ^C? можно записывать в вим эти значения без каких-либо доп редактирований `.vimrc` - я точно это знаю, просто не запомнил, какие клавиши нажимал.

Comment: ничего не понял, но попробую начать с начала. у вас есть некая команда, выполнив которую, вы переопределяете поведение `ctrl+d`. вы можете вводить эту команду каждый раз, когда вам потребуется такое поведение, и оно сохранится, пока запущен тот процесс vim, в котором вы выполнили эту команду. если же вам надо, чтобы для получения такого поведения не требовалось вводить команду каждый раз, то можете поместить эту команду в `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: но мне представляется всё это (по крайней мере в том виде, как я вас понял), чересчур усложнённым. разве не проще ли не переопределять поведение `ctrl+d`, а просто нажать перед `ctrl+d` сочетание `ctrl+v`? по-моему, это гораздо проще.

Comment: Я и спрашивал об этом!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нажатие в режиме вставки сочетания <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> приведёт к тому, что следующий символ будет введён «буквально» (*literally*).

для некоторых символов это будет означать ввод т.н. «терминального кода» (*terminal code*).

например, если нажать <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, а затем, например, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, то в файл будет записан символ [*eot* (end-of-transmission)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character), который в т.н. [*caret notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) изображают как `^D`.